# Generating a video with web technologies from a template?

Tags: php, templates, video, edit

I am looking to create a system that will let a user create a video based on say an after effects file, or any others ( a premade template) but it would populate the users information in it instead. I am looking for a way or a technology that can help me do so?

Is it possible to accomplish with PHP, or Javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

search about program to do you wont but in linux base , so you can use php exec() function as api (command line) for any program work on linux